# Jmeter no encuentra ruta de Java

Tags: java, jmeter

actualmente estoy trabajando con la herramienta de Jmeter, al ejecutar la herramienta me esta presentando el siguiente error en consola:

```
./jmeter.sh: 99: [: Illegal number:
./jmeter: 128: [: Illegal number: 
./jmeter: 199: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java: not found
```

*NOTA: No se si el error tenga que ver por la ruta que me devuelve la consola "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java", ya que, la parte final de esta aparece duplicada*

Creo que el error fue provocado al definir la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME, ya que, antes de la configuración de la variable, Jmeter funcionaba, pero no he encontrado la manera de solucionar el error, agradeceria la ayuda, muchas gracias.

Adjunto evidencias del error

1- Error al ejecutar Jmeter
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2- echo de la variable de entorno
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Variables de entorno en etc/profile/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando en el sistema operativo Linux

Comment: Vamos por partes, busca en "/etc/" el archivo environment, y muestranos su contenido.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, este es el contenido del archivo environment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Modifica /etc/environment para que quede así:

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"

- Verifica que realmente tienes la jvm en **/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java**.
- actualiza desde la consola, la info del sistema:

  source "/etc/environment"
  echo -e ’export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"\nextport PATH="$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"’ | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/java-11-openjdk-amd64.sh
- Si con eso no alcanza ejecuta lo siguiente:

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" 0

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" 0

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac

Comment: Hola, ya logre ejecutar Jmeter, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Grande maestro!!